# The relationship between server response status and server received time

Tags: android, mysql, http, server

I am currently working on storing image file into the mysql database. I have a web server and I have mysql database and php for server-side scripting.

I am able to store images into the database from the Android device and I am using okhttp to send data from Android to the server(database).

I create a request with

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://my_server_ip_address/upload.php").post(request_body).build();
```

and I get response from the server with

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

When I check if the server responded with

```
if(response.isSuccessful())
    Log.d("------", response.message());
```

I get "OK" meaning that the server response is good and I see that the file is uploaded into my database.

My question is that does "OK" response from server mean that the server received the image file? or is it just a message that says the server responded to client no matter the server received the image file or not?

What I am trying to do is that I want to get the exact time of it that the server received the image file.

If that is not meaning that the server received the image, then how can we get the exact time of server stored the image I uploaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, server responds 200 OK in the header. So you are getting OK in the log. If the image upload fails, you have to respond 40x from the server.